# Поиск всех значений в массиве по совпадению без цикла

Tags: php

Есть ассоциативный массив нужно выбрать конкретные значения по совпадению и хотелось бы сделать все это без цикла, так как массивы могут быть большие, подскажите как это можно реализовать?
К примеру:

```
0 =>[
  'user'=> 'ivan'
  'amount' => 50
  'date' => '2019'
  ],
1=>  [
  'user'=> 'dima'
  'amount' => 10
  'date' => '2019'
  ],
2=>  [
  'user'=> 'ivan'
  'amount' => 11
  'date' => '2019'
  ],
```

мне нужно оставить к примеру `ivan` и чтобы на выходе получить такое:

```
0 =>[
      'user'=> 'ivan'
      'amount' => 50
      'date' => '2019'
      ],
1=>  [
      'user'=> 'ivan'
      'amount' => 11
      'date' => '2019'
      ],
```

Comment: А где ваш код? Хотя бы попытки.

Comment: @doox911 сделать я смогу и мой код с циклом тут будет не уместен,   я хочу узнать возможно ли сделать без цикла

Answer (score 2):

*Следует понимать*, что если цикл не прописан явно в скрипте, то это *совсем* не означает, что цикла не будет вообще. Следует, также, понимать, что перебрать массив без цикла **в принципе невозможно**. То есть, цикл будет, независимо от пожеланий автора вопроса.

Также следует понимать, что в погоне за оптимизацией можно получить результат, прямо противоположный ожидаемому. Что мы и имеем в данном случае - в попытке избежать одного цикла автор вопроса в результате в одном из ответов получил **два**: один цикл чтобы перебрать исходный массив, и второй - чтобы перебрать результирующий.

Мораль: задача поиска в массиве без цикла не имеет смысла.

Comment: да вы правы , но я протестировал результат не значителен к примеру я создал массив на 100000 записей и у меня получилось следующие результаты

float(0.53402996063232) -- array_filter  и 
float(0.49602890014648) -- foreach

Answer (score 0):

> *сделать все это без цикла*

Можно отфильтровать массив с помощью [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), и сбросить ключи с помощью *array_values()*:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'user'=> 'ivan',
        'amount' => 50,
        'date' => '2019'
    ],
    [
        'user'=> 'dima',
        'amount' => 10,
        'date' => '2019'
    ],
    [
        'user'=> 'ivan',
        'amount' => 11,
        'date' => '2019'
    ]
];

$arr = array_values(array_filter($arr, function($a){
    return in_array('ivan', $a);
}));

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => ivan
            [amount] => 50
            [date] => 2019
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => ivan
            [amount] => 11
            [date] => 2019
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

спасибо , 
немного доработал , как мне кажется без доп функции in_arr будет быстрее

```
$search = 'ivan';
$res = array_filter($arr, function($v) use ($search){
     return $v['user'] == $search;
});
```

Comment: вот так _(без проверки типов)_ будет быстрее: `return $v['user'] == $search;`